# tensorflow malloc error "pointer being freed was not allocated"

Tags: tensorflow, malloc

I'm suddenly running into this error while trying to run my tensorflow code. It was working perfectly fine before, but now I'm suddenly getting this error. After googling it, there was only one mention of this error popping up in tensorflow, but the fix was to upgrade to tf 1.7 (this was 5 years ago). I am trying to run it with tensorflow 2.15 on a Mac M3 Max.

The expected behavior is to not crash when running $sess.run(..)$ to get a basic prediction in eager execution mode with v2 behavior disabled.

Instead I get the error at the bottom of this complete stack trace:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/compat/v2_compat.py:108: disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
non-resource variables are not supported in the long term
/Users/paullintilhac/code/pdfclassifier/train/model.py:18: UserWarning: `tf.layers.dense` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `tf.keras.layers.Dense` instead.
  h_fc1 = tf.layers.dense(self.x_input, 200, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="fc1")
/Users/paullintilhac/code/pdfclassifier/train/model.py:19: UserWarning: `tf.layers.dense` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `tf.keras.layers.Dense` instead.
  h_fc2 = tf.layers.dense(h_fc1, 200, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="fc2")
/Users/paullintilhac/code/pdfclassifier/train/model.py:21: UserWarning: `tf.layers.dense` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `tf.keras.layers.Dense` instead.
  self.pre_softmax = tf.layers.dense(h_fc2, 2, activation=None, name="pre_softmax")
python3(1815,0x1e0f91ec0) malloc: *** error for object 0x2a8987964: pointer being freed was not allocated
python3(1815,0x1e0f91ec0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Here is my very simple code example (this is the same exact error I get when running with my much more complex program):

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from model import Model
tf.disable_eager_execution()
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
x_test = [[float(0)]*3514]
model = Model()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    PATH = "../models/adv_trained/baseline_adv_combine_two.ckpt"
    saver.restore(sess, PATH)
    y = sess.run(model.y_pred,\
                        feed_dict={model.x_input:x_test
                })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best,

Paul

EDIT:
After doing some debugging on this error, I found that actually it is the import of the `xgboost` library that seems to be controlling whether or not this error appears. there must be some kind of naming collision or improper thread safety of the two libraries running simultaneouslt or something?

EDIT 2:
I tried updating to tensorflow v2 and following the correct way to load a v1 checkpoint. My example now looks like this.

So, now with code that looks like this (note the `import model_v2` which imports my updated model class):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from model_v2 import Model
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
PATH = "../models/adv_trained/baseline_adv_combine_two_v2.ckpt-20.index"
x_test = [[float(0)]*3514]
model = Model()
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(variables=[model])
checkpoint.restore( PATH)
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    # tf.train.list_variables(PATH)
    checkpoint.restore( PATH)
    y = sess.run(model.y_pred,\
                        feed_dict={model.x_input:x_test
                })
```

I get a new error:

```
Restoring a name-based tf.train.Saver checkpoint using the object-based restore API. This mode uses global names to match variables, and so is somewhat fragile. It also adds new restore ops to the graph each time it is called when graph building. Prefer re-encoding training checkpoints in the object-based format: run save() on the object-based saver (the same one this message is coming from) and use that checkpoint in the future.
```

It's strange, because it says that the checkpoint was from `tf.train.saver`, when in reality I saved it using `tf.train.Checkpoint.save`. So I'm not sure how to interpret this error.

Comment: This looks like an issue you should report to the TensorFlow team on [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues). However, given that you are using deprecated functions, and a compatibility layer to TF 1, I guess this will not be the highest priority bug to fix. I would recommend to use the last stable version of TF 1 (the 1.15) to run your code, unless you really need some of the features of TF 2.

Comment: unfortunately, I am on an M3 Max, so I do not have native access to python<3.8. Which means I can't install tensorflow 1.x. The best I can do is use `tensorflow.compat.v1` which I'm already doing

Answer (score 1):

I have never faced this problem myself, but the TF2 [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/Saver) explicitly says that:

> `tf.compat.v1.train.Saver` is not supported for saving and restoring checkpoints in TF2. Please switch to `tf.train.Checkpoint` or `tf.keras.Model.load_weights`, which perform a more robust object-based saving.

So I would try to use those other functions to restore and convert the TF1 session to TF2 format as described in the "How to Rewrite Checkpoints" section...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried that but now I'm running into a new error (see edit 2 above). that looks like its coming from the fact that the model is a v1 model. I tried doing the same conversion for my actual program of interest, and I'm getting an error saying `alueError: Expected values [array([1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1])] to be a dense tensor with shape [1], but got shape [1, 3514].` I guess there is some issue loading the v1 model?

Comment: Also, if I try using instead `tf.compat.v1.train.Checkpoint(model)`, I get the error: `TypeError: CheckpointV1.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. It's not clear to me how to get this to work from the documentation, which references a model variable that is never declared, and mixes up `tf.compat.v1` methods with `tf` methods without exaplanation... any example of how I would do this with my code would be super helpful!

Comment: I do not have access to TF1, so I was just blindly guessing. What about the `tf.keras.Model.load_weights(path)` option, maybe that gives something more useful? Or can you see anything by running `tf.train.list_variables(path)`?

Comment: I can try to make that work, but at this point I'm doubtful that my system is compatible with tf1 at all. the output of `tf.train.list_variables(PATH)` is `tensorflow variables: [('_CHECKPOINTABLE_OBJECT_GRAPH', []), ('save_counter/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', [])]`

Comment: the issue with load_weights is that I'm trying to load a v1 model, not a keras model.

Comment: ok, so it turns out that I had a syntax error in the way I was initializing the checkpoint, which sould have been `checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(variables=[model])`. Once I did this I got the error in my edit 2. turns out the variables weren't (re-?)initialized after the model was restored, which they should have been. Once I did that, I got it to work in my toy example at least. my answer below

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my conversation with @gabalz, it turned out that I did indeed need to update to the proper way of loading the model. I just had a syntax error in the way I was trying to load the model.

The correct working code for this toy example is given below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from model import Model
import xgboost as xgb
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
PATH = "../models/adv_trained/baseline_adv_combine_two.ckpt"
x_test = [[float(0)]*3514]
model = Model()
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(variables=[model])
checkpoint.restore( PATH)
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    # tf.train.list_variables(PATH)
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.local_variables_initializer())
    checkpoint.restore( PATH)
    y = sess.run(model.y_pred,\
                        feed_dict={model.x_input:x_test
                })
```

After doing an ablation experiment, it turns out I didn't need to update my model code to v2, nor save the model initially using the `checkpoint` class -- I can still use the model save with `saver` using `checkpoint`. Though I do get the warning (in my edit 2 above) when I try to load a model saved with saver, so its probably advisable to update the code for saving as well.

Also, it didn't matter whether I used `tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint` or `tf.train.Checkpoint`

Note that I am able to import xgboost again without an error.

EDIT:
To add to the above answer, it turns out that actually the saver wasn't even the root cause of the original malloc error. What ended up solving it in the end was simply moving xbgoost to be the last import. It seems that some names are colliding between `xgboost` and `tensorflow`, so the order of the imports matters. This is just a bandaid actually, but definitely the quickest and easiest solution to my problem, and something I wish I had thought of initially.

-Paul

Comment: Nice work Paul!